# Compare cells of two rows of a datagrid view highlighing the ones that dont match

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

This what I have. A query that takes data from two different database of the same table. giving each a row_number() and Location along with data of all the relevant columns i need to evaluate. so i have two rows with the first col of 1 and the second col of the first is Home the second row second col is remote. and then all the columns to compare. there could be as few as 5 relevant columns up 31 depending on the table being compared.
So my C# code populates the DGV then i start going through each col 2, row 1 compare col 2 row 2 if not equal make each cell red.
then next col col3 row 1, Col3 row 2 all the way down the list of col's for the row pair.
its not to bad on 40 row pair and 10 col's but i have some instances of 4800 row pairs and 30 col's. 
does anyone have a faster way then row by cell. i have thoght about taking my slq query and setting some flag?? at my wits end.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty fast. 
Note: I'm not excluding row_number() column, doing NULL checks, etc...

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.RowIndex > 0) && (e.ColumnIndex > 0) && ((e.RowIndex % 2) == 0))
            {
                if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.CellBounds);
                    e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```